# Renovate: packageRules are not treated separetly

Tags: github-actions, renovate

We are currently using this renovate config in different repos:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
  "extends": [
    "config:base"
  ],
  "labels": ["dependencies"],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["minor", "patch"],
      "automerge": true,
      "automergeType": "branch",
      "pruneBranchAfterAutomerge": true
    },
    {
        "matchDatasources": ["golang-version"],
        "rangeStrategy": "bump",
    }
  ]
}
```

We want to auto-merge everything that is `minor` or `patch` and just open a PR in case the dependency that is updated is the "golang-version" itself.

However, in the repo we are testing this change renovate is trying to auto-merge everything!

[image]

On the other hand, renovate does not open the PR or auto-merge the `golang-version` dependency without:

```
    {
        "matchDatasources": ["golang-version"],
        "rangeStrategy": "bump",
    }
```

In the logs, it says that somehow auto-merge is set to true, but the default should be false for the second packageRule!
`DEBUG: Branch automerge is enabled (branch="renovate/go-1.x")`

Comment: What version bumps are detected? Isn't the golang bump detected a minor or patch one?

Comment: Golang bump is detected a a minor from 1.19 to 1.20

Comment: so it match the rules you defined: if minor bump then automerge. If you want to exclude golang from this rule, you need to change the rule with a `matchDatasources` exclusing golang (don't remember the syntax but should be defined in the documentation).

Answer (score 0):

This is a general Renovate configuration question. "Everything that is not forbidden is allowed." Very often or almost always.
If you want to disallow something, disallow it explicitly with 'false'.
For example:

```
{  
  "matchUpdateTypes": ["major"],
  "automerge": false
}
```

Or you can disable 'automerge' completely, and then, in the next packageRules block, enable 'automerge' for a specific package or dependency type. And you can add many such blocks. The JSON configuration file will be executed from top to bottom. Therefore, it is important to add rules in the order in which they must be executed.